# Вывести иерархию дерева через "/" в PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

У меня есть таблица с полями
    id,
    parent_id,
    code,
    name
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Делаю простой запрос рекурсии на вывод иерархии дерева. Работает норм

```
  WITH RECURSIVE r AS (
        SELECT 
            p.id,
            p.parent_id,
            p.code,
            p.name as title
        FROM portal.orgunits p
        WHERE name Like 'Bergnaum - Hand'

        UNION

        SELECT 
            ou.id,
            ou.parent_id,
            ou.code, 
            ou.name
        FROM portal.orgunits ou
                 INNER JOIN r ON ou.id = r.parent_id
        )
        SELECT * FROM r
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видете я получаю результат иерархии для поиска по имени. Первая строка это то что я искал и следующие строки идут в порядке вложености.

Сейчас мне нужно сконкотенировать иерерахию с верхней ноды до последней и получить по факту вот такой результат: `Ledner - Witting/Kunde - Spencer/Bergnaum - Hand`

Я пытался делать вот так:

```
WITH RECURSIVE r AS (
        SELECT 
            p.id,
            p.parent_id,
            p.code,
            p.name as title,
           concat_ws('/', p.name) as pathUrl
        FROM portal.orgunits p
        WHERE name Like 'Bergnaum - Hand'

        UNION

        SELECT 
            ou.id,
            ou.parent_id,
            ou.code, 
            ou.name,
            concat_ws('/', ou.name, r.title) as pathUrl
        FROM portal.orgunits ou
                 INNER JOIN r ON ou.id = r.parent_id
        )
        SELECT pathUrl FROM r
```

Вроде как бы напрвление правильное но результат у меня вот такой. Не совсем что нужно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как видете конкотенация происходит только с одним уровнем выше. а нужно вообще получить на выходи лиш одну стрингу в поле pathUrl как я описал выше. Как написать такой запрос?

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. Дайте ответ и отмечу как правильный

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итеративной части CTE заменить

```
concat_ws('/', ou.name, r.title) as pathUrl
```

на

```
concat_ws('/', ou.name, r.pathUrl) as pathUrl
```